# SNOWFLAKE - PIVOT QUERY

Tags: pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Table 1:

```
ID AUDIT_KEY Col_Name
1  100        FULL NAME
2  101        FNAME
3  102        LNAME
4  103        ADDR1
```

Table 2:

```
ID_key  AUDITKEY  Col_Value
1       100       john abraham
2       101       johny
3       102       Abraham
4       103       6900 Forester Rd

1  104       Praveen Gupta
2  105       Praveen
3  106       Gupta
4  107       3200 Walter RD
```

Looking for QUERY TO FORM THE RESULT AS BELOW

```
ID NAME           FNAME    LNAME     ADDR1
1  JOHN ABRAHAM   JOHNY    ABRAHAM   6900 Forester Rd
2  PRAVEEN GUPTA  PRAVEEN  GUPTA     3200 WALTER RD
```

Written pivot query on table1 when i join table2 based on the ID & ID_KEY is not working.. any idea folks..

```
SELECT ID, NAME,FNAME,LNAME,ADDR1 
FROM TABLE1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID 
PIVOT (MAX(TABLE1.COL_NAME) 
       FOR TABLE2.COL_VALUE IN ('ID','NAME','FNAME','LNAME','ADDR1')) AS TMP
```

Comment: Please show the query that's not working, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: SELECT ID, NAME,FNAME,LNAME,ADDR1 FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID PIVOT (MAX(TABLE1.COL_NAME) FOR TABLE2.COL_VALUE IN ('ID','NAME','FNAME','LNAME','ADDR1')) AS TMP ...Question here is, not accepting inner join...any thoughts..

Comment: don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the join in a CTE and then do the pivot against the product of that.  something along the lines of:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT t1.col_name, t2.col_value
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
  ) 
SELECT *
PIVOT (MAX(COL_NAME) 
       FOR COL_VALUE IN ('NAME','FNAME','LNAME','ADDR1')) AS TMP;
```

Note - I haven't tested this myself, so see if it works.  I don't think Snowflake likes join and pivot in the same query, so doing the join inside a CTE provides a single table input into the pivot function.

Also, note, you had 'ID' in the `IN` clause, but that isn't a col_value value in your sample data, so you don't want it there.  That could also be your issue.

Comment: Thanks Mike. But the above that you have given throwing an syntax error.. I thought that from clause is missing in second sql and after i added x with or without it is not working..

Comment: Ok - let me setup a sample and try and fix my syntax.  :-)

Comment: I think I see a potential issue.  How are you getting ID = 1 and ID = 2 in your output table?  There is no ID to actually pivot on in your example tables.

Comment: without ID columns there is no gurantee that we have pivoted correctly for col_name and it's corresponding value.. am i right?

Comment: But I have nothing to pivot on.  There is nothing in your current data tells me that the rows in table 1 and table 2 should be pivoted into a single row.  For example, what data point tells me that 101 and 103 in table 2 are related to each other?