# SQL function to download rows with specific values only

Tags: sql, hive

I have duplicate IDs with different activities. To return all the IDs, but remove duplicates, and to return three new columns called email, phone call and appointment containing true if activity is (email(for email columns), phone call(for phone column), appointment(for appointment columns)), otherwise false.

**What I have**

| ID | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Email |
| 101 | Appointment |
| 102 | Campaign |
| 103 | Phone call |
| 104 | Appointment |

```
SELECT id,

MAX(CASE WHEN activity='Phone Call' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS PhoneCall, 
MAX(CASE WHEN activity='Appointment' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS Appointment,
MAX(CASE WHEN activity='Email' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS Email
```

| 104      | Campaign    |

**What I want**

| ID | Email | Appointment | Phone call |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | True | True | False |
| 102 | False | False | False |
| 103 | False | False | Ture |
| 104 | False | Ture | False |

Comment: you can use pivot - here is an example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65691065/snowflake-pivot-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for

```
SELECT id, MAX(CASE WHEN activity='Email' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS Email, MAX(CASE WHEN activity='Appointment' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS Appointment, MAX(CASE WHEN activity='Phone Call' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS 'Phone Call' FROM {your_table_name} GROUP BY id;
```